# Populate method in mongoose virtual: nothing is being returned.

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, virtual, populate

I have a problem with the definition of virtuals for my commentSchema. In the commentSchema I have a reference to the "User" model. I try to get the "comment.user.username" attribute. for this I've defined the virtual attribute "author", where I populate the comment and get the username, but it is not being returned. :(

CommentSchema:

```
var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String },
  text: String,
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  ....
```

})

UserSchema:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   local : {
         username : String,
         email: String,
    ...
   })
```

In my ejs-File I have a angular ng-repeat form where I want to access the attributes of the comment documents:

```
<dd data-ng-repeat="comment in comments" class="accordion-navigation">
     <a id="lastStop" href="#panel{{ $index }}">{{ comment.title }}</a>
```

It works for all attribuets except of virtuals. Here is the Definition of virtual:

```
commentSchema.virtual('author').get(function () {
  mongoose.model('Comment').findOne({ title : this.title })
  .populate('user')
  .exec(function(err, comment) {
    if (comment.user) {
      console.log(comment.user.local.username);
      return comment.user.local.username;
    }  else {
      return "Anonymous"
    }    
  });

 }
```

)

Nothing is being returned. Any ideas?